# Directive gives me error when try to access scope variable from compile function

Tags: angularjs

When I try to make directive for display content and tooltip but I need to initialize scope variable 'name' in compile function.

```js
sampleApp.directive('secondPage',function($compile){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template:'<h3>Second Page Directive Content Displaying using directive scope <u>{{name}}</u></h3>',
        scope:false,
        controller: function( $scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude ) {
            $scope.name = 'Angular Js';
        },
        compile: function (element, attrs) {

        element.attr('tooltip', '{{dt()}}');
        element.attr('tooltip-placement', 'bottom');
        element.removeAttr("common-things"); //remove the attribute to avoid indefinite loop
        element.removeAttr("data-common-things"); //also remove the same attribute with data- prefix in case users specify data-common-things in the html

        return {
          pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  },
          post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  
            $compile(iElement)(scope);              
          }
        };
        }       
    }

});
```

Html Code --

```
<div ng-controller="MySecondController">
 <h2 ng-bind='message'></h2>
 <second-page name='Second Page'></second-page>
</div>
```

Comment: `compile` function don't have access to `$scope`

Comment: thanks for reply but according to you compile function don't have access to $scope. But then how i intialize Scope varible value in directory.

Comment: Its not my opinion, by Angular architecture you can't access scope in compile function, because it executes just before initializing controller... Let it be,  What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I want using directive just print template text and on it on hover tooltip but text have use one scope variable value print

Comment: Try to move your code inside the `link:` function, which will be executed after the compile function

Answer (score 0):

```
function post(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
    var name = iAttrs.name;
    $compile(iElem)(angular.extend(scope.$new(), {name: name}));
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but  we need to put in pre not post. Bacause of pre into create variable and assign value in controller then it will display perfectly